# Basic awk - Filter with awk with slash in command line

Tags: awk, command-line

Quick question.

```
df -h
```

Gives following output

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev
tmpfs           302M  8.5M  294M   3% /run
/dev/sda1       144G   28G  109G  21% /
tmpfs           1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
```

***Goal***: Expecting output for the line with `/dev/sda1`

```
109G/144G available, 21% used.
```

Following command not working as expected.

```
df -h | awk '/dev/sda { print $4"/"$2" available, "$5" used." }'
```

Gives following.

```
Avail/Size available, Use% used.
1.5G/1.5G available, 0% used.
294M/302M available, 3% used.
109G/144G available, 21% used.
1.5G/1.5G available, 0% used.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need small correction

From

```
/dev/sda
```

To

```
/dev\/sda/
```

Will become

```
awk '/dev\/sda/ { print $4"/"$2" available, "$5" used." }'
```

Comment: Is `/` at the begining and ending of `/dev\/sda/` indicating it's regex string?

Comment: @ClintonLam yes `/<this is your pattern or regex>/`